# What makes the radius too long in the following PS expression?

Tags: pstricks, postscript, pst-node

I want to translate

```
\pstVerb{/Dist {N-A.x N-A.y N-B.x N-B.y Pyth2} def}
```

from the following

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,45,-90}]
        (-1.5,-1){A}
        (1.5,1){B}
    \pstVerb{/Dist {N-A.x N-A.y N-B.x N-B.y Pyth2} def}%
    \pnode[A](!Dist 21 PtoC){D}\psdots(D)
    \psarc[origin={A},arcsep=-1](A){!Dist}{(D)}{(B)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

to

```
 \pstVerb{%
        tx@Dict begin
            tx@NodeDict begin
                /N@A load GetCenter
                /N@B load GetCenter
            end
            Pyth2 \pst@number\psrunit\space div
            /Dist ED
        end}%
```

used in

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={12pt 12pt 25cm 15cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\makeatletter
\psset{runit=\psunit}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,45,-90}]
        (-1.5,-1){A}
        (1.5,1){B}
    \pstVerb{%
            tx@Dict begin
                tx@NodeDict begin
                    /N@A load GetCenter
                    /N@B load GetCenter
                end
                Pyth2 \pst@number\psrunit\space div
                /Dist ED
            end}%
    \pnode[A](!Dist 21 PtoC){D}\psdots(D)
    \psarc[origin={A},arcsep=-1](A){!Dist}{(D)}{(B)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

What is my mistake caused the radius to be too long?

Edit: The problem solved when `Pyth2 \pst@number\psrunit\space div` is replaced by `Pyth2 236 div`. But it still leaves a question, why is it `236`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pst-eucl` has a distance function so why making things so complicated?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={12pt 12pt 25cm 15cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,45,-90}](-1.5,-1){A}(1.5,1){B}(1.5,-1){C}
    \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{C}{B}
    \pnode[A](!\pstDistAB{A}{B} 21 PtoC \tx@UserCoor){D}\psdots(D)
    \psarc[origin={A},arcsep=-1](A){!\pstDistAB{A}{B} \pst@number\psunit div}{(D)}{(B)}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)(D|C)(C)
    \psset{shortput=nab,labelsep=-3pt}
    \ncline{A}{B}^{$g$}
    \ncline{B}{C}^{$a$}
    \ncline{C}{A}^{$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually the question I posted is to be my experiment how to use dictionaries.

Comment: then use another simple example ...

Comment: Ok. Now the codes have been simplified.